# Installed and uninstalled ubuntu-gnome-desktop and now my computer uses two-finger scroll instead of edge scroll. How do I go back?

Tags: gnome, touchpad

I have the standard ubuntu 16.10 distribution with the standard unity desktop environment. I installed `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` out of curiosity, but it was malfunctioning a lot, so I uninstalled it using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge ubuntu-gnome-desktop
sudo apt autoremove
sudo reboot
sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove ubuntu-gnome-desktop
for i in abiword abiword-common abiword-plugin-grammar abiword-plugin-mathview alacarte argyll cups-pk-helper epiphany-browser epiphany-browser-data evolution evolution-common evolution-plugins fonts-cantarell fonts-lyx gdm gir1.2-accountsservice-1.0 gir1.2-caribou-1.0 gir1.2-clutter-gst-2.0 gir1.2-evince-3.0 gir1.2-gck-1 gir1.2-gconf-2.0 gir1.2-gcr-3 gir1.2-gdesktopenums-3.0 gir1.2-gkbd-3.0 gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0 gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0 gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0 gir1.2-ibus-1.0 gir1.2-mutter-3.0 gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0 gir1.2-panelapplet-4.0 gir1.2-polkit-1.0 gir1.2-telepathyglib-0.12 gir1.2-telepathylogger-0.2 gir1.2-upowerglib-1.0 gir1.2-xkl-1.0 gjs glchess glines gnect gnibbles gnobots2 gnome-applets gnome-applets-data gnome-color-manager gnome-desktop-data gnome-dictionary gnome-games gnome-games-extra-data gnome-icon-theme-extras gnome-mahjongg gnome-packagekit gnome-packagekit-data gnome-panel gnome-panel-data gnome-search-tool gnome-session-fallback gnome-shell gnome-shell-common gnome-software-manager gnome-sushi gnome-tweak-tool gnome-update-viewer gnotravex gnotski gnumeric gnumeric-common gnumeric-doc gstreamer1.0-alsa gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio gstreamer1.0-tools gtali iagno itstool libabiword-2.9 libaudit0 libcaribou-common libcaribou0 libcolamd2.7.1 libcolord-gtk1 libedataserverui-3.0-4 libevolution libgdict-1.0-6 libgdict-common libgdome2-0 libgdome2-cpp-smart0c2a libgjs0c libgoffice-0.8-8 libgoffice-0.8-8-common libgtkmathview0c2a libicc2 libimdi0 libiptcdata0 liblink-grammar4 libloudmouth1-0 libmail-spf-perl libmozjs185-1.0 libmutter0 libnetaddr-ip-perl libots0 libpst4 libtidy-0.99-0 libtracker-extract-0.14-0 libtracker-miner-0.14-0 libtracker-sparql-0.14-0 libwv-1.2-4 libytnef0 lightsoff link-grammar-dictionaries-en mutter mutter-common packagekit packagekit-backend-aptcc packagekit-tools plymouth-theme-ubuntu-gnome-logo plymouth-theme-ubuntu-gnome-text python-cloudfiles python-packagekit quadrapassel re2c simple-scan spamassassin spamc swell-foop tracker tracker-extract tracker-gui tracker-miner-fs tracker-utils ubuntu-gnome-default-settings ubuntu-gnome-desktop xsltproc yelp-tools; do sudo apt-get -y purge $i; done
```

However, after all this, my computer still uses two finger scrolling, whereas it used edgescrolling before installing ubuntu-gnome-desktop. I orginally switched to edgescrolling using the option in Unity Tweak Tool, but now it seems that option has no effect as my computer uses two finger scroll regardless of what that option is set to. I have also lost the ability to click via toubletapping my trackpad.

Anyone know how I can restore my trackpad to it's previous functioning?

Comment: Installing a new desktop is easy but once done reverting never is.

Comment: Any idea how to solve the problem?

Comment: I may not be possible but wait for answers.

Comment: Check how your touchpad settings are configured _(under Unity settings -> Mouse and touchpad)_

Comment: Possibly a stupid question: where are unity settings?

Comment: I mean ususal _system settings_. If changing settings from there doesn't work, try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure synaptic`, if still doesn't work you'll have to find differing udev rules which could be created while installing _Gnome_, etc. At this point, you should evaluate reinstalling from scratch. Hope it helps.

Comment: Bizarrely, I have now realized I am no longer able to open my system settings. Going to reinstall